# Where do I place base action class in Symfony plugin?

Tags: plugins, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-plugins

I'm creating a plugin for my symfony project, which includes a base action class, i.e.:

```
<?php
// myActions.class.php
class myActions extends sfActions {
    /* ... */
}
```

Where in my plugin folder (e.g.: `plugins/sfMyPlugin/???`) should I place this file?

The goal is to have actions that are NOT a part of this plugin extend this class, hopefully having the class be autoloaded (similar to if it were placed under `apps/my_app/lib`).  If it can't be autoloaded, how do I get symfony to include my php file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typically put it in your plugin's `lib` directory. The general conventions is also to to name with `Base` in the name so given your example that would be `BasemyActions`. Then you would also make an empty concrete class called `myActions` and you would extend that within your plugin thus allowing other user to complety replace `myActions` with their own implementation (so long as it extends the base class) or to simply extend `myActions`.

Comment: Thanks! I did that originally, and it didn't work. I just tried it again, and it worked, so I must have had a misspelling or something.

Answer (score 2):

you can place it in the lib directory of your plugin. This is what the generate:plugin-module task of the [sfTaskExtraPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/blog/2008/11/08/additional-tasks-to-streamline-your-workflow) does.